# "using" construct and exception handling

Tags: c#, design-patterns, exception, language-features

The "[using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)" construct looks incredibly handy for situations that require both beginning and separated end parts.

Quick example to illustrate:

```
using (new Tag("body")) {
    Trace.WriteLine("hello!");
}
// ...
class Tag : IDisposable {
    String name;
    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        Trace.WriteLine("<" + this.name + ">");
        Trace.Indent();
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        Trace.Unindent();
        Trace.WriteLine("</" + this.name + ">")
    }
}
```

The beginning part is defined as the constructor, the end part is the Dispose method.

However despite of being attractive this construct has a serious caveat that comes from the fact that the Dispose method is called from within a finally block. So there are 2 problems:

1. You should avoid throwing exceptions from the finally block because they will override the original exception that was supposed to be caught.
2. There is no way of knowing inside of the Dispose method if an exception was thrown earlier between "beginning" and "end" and thus there is no way of handling the "end" part accordingly.

These 2 things make using of this construct impractical which is a very sad fact.
Now, my questions are:

1. Is my understanding of the problems right? Is this how "using" actually works?
2. If so, is there any way to overcome these problems and make practical use of the "using" construct other than what it was originally designed for (releasing resources and cleaning up)
3. In case there is no practical way for "using" to be used this way. What are the alternative approaches (to enforce the context over some code with the beginning and end parts)?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865920/disposable-context-object-pattern  for more on the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent of the `using` statement and of the `IDisposable` interface is for the user to dispose of unmanaged resources. These resources are usually expensive and precious, so they must be disposed of no matter what (that's why it's on the `finally`). Code in `finally` blocks can't even be aborted, and it can hang a whole app domain shutdown.

Now, it's very tempting to abuse `using` for the purposes you're describing, and I've done that in the past. Most of the time there's [no danger there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5793154/31158). But if an unexpected exception happens, the whole state of the processing is compromised, you wouldn't necessarily want to run the end operation; so in general, don't do this.

An alternative is to use a lambda, something like this:

```
public interface IScopable { 
  void EndScope();
}

public class Tag : IScopable {
  private string name;
  public Tag(string name) {
    this.name = name;
    Trace.WriteLine("<" + this.name + ">");
    Trace.Indent();
  }
  public void EndScope() {
    Trace.Unindent();
    Trace.WriteLine("</" + this.name + ">");
  }
}

public static class Scoping {
  public static void Scope<T>(this T scopable, Action<T> action) 
    where T : IScopable {
    action(scopable);
    scopable.EndScope();
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
new Tag("body").Scope(_ => 
  Trace.WriteLine("hello!")
);
```

You can also create other implementations that run certain actions based on whether exceptions were raised of not.

In Nemerle, the language [can be extended with new syntax](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2011/04/more-macros-in-nemerle.html) to support this.

Comment: yes, it seems like using a wrapped anonymous function is the only working alternative for this, although I don't like this idea because it doesn't look elegant plus it drags in all caveats with using closures

Comment: I ended up using lambdas. It's not the most efficient way, but very intuitive and does what it needs to just right. So your answer won.

Answer (score 5):

Your rule #1 applies with or without `using`, so the rule #2 is the real decider: opt for a `try`/`catch` if you must distinguish between situations when an exception has been thrown and the normal program completion.

For example, if your persistence layer may discover issues in the process of using a database connection, your connection needs to close regardless of the fact that there was an exception. In this case, the `using` construct is a perfect choice.

In some cases you can set up `using` specifically to detect normal completion vs. an exceptional completion. Ambient transactions provide a perfect example:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
    // Do something that may throw an exception
    scope.Complete();
}
```

If `scope`'s `Dispose` is called before `Complete` has been called, `TransactionScope` knows that an exception has been thrown, and aborts the transaction.

Comment: not a very good example with having to call scope.Complete explicitly, because it makes the whole idea of "using" useless. You have to remember doing it everywhere, which is not much different from plain calling scope.Begin() and scope.End() around your code.

Comment: But that's precisely the idea behind `TransactionScope`! Regardless of the path that leads to not calling `Complete` the `scope` knows that something went wrong (incidentally, "going wrong" includes "forgetting to call `Complete` during the coding phase"). And the scope is there to detect situations when something went wrong: your call of `Complete` is your vote that this part of the transaction went fine.

Comment: the whole `using` block is half-baked. you can find gazillion of cases where it would fail because of different issues. I wish I'd get an explanation from .net engineers one day how they really expected/expecting people to use it and when it is not a good practice. In this particular case, msdn states that anyone who uses `TransactionScope` must call its `Complete()` method when he finishes using it..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I understand the semantics of calling the scope.Complete in your example, and having to do that is a flaw, because it's easy to forget and thus, in this particular case, it is deceiving that you can rely on using to define the scope, having using alone is not enough, so why would you bother with having it at all? sorry, it's not personal :)

Comment: @YavgenyP If your code detects a situation when a transaction should not be committed, it is allowed to leave the `using` block without calling `Complete`. The `using` block is no more "half-baked" than, say, an `if` statement is :) It is a fully defined feature of the language. When used correctly, it helps you greatly to reduce the clutter.

Comment: @bonomo The fact that the feature fails to live up to your expectations has nothing to do with the feature itself, and everything to do with your expectations. Forgetting to call `Complete` is no more "a flaw" of the `using` statement than forgetting to put a semicolon at the end of a line is "a flaw" of the C# compiler :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, well whole purpose of using to be syntactic sugar that was supposed to make my life easier by making me type less and **by leaving me no room for forgetting to execute the "end" part**. which isn't the case here, thus it's still sugar but with a good hint of bitterness

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this was the original intention of `IDisposable`, but Microsoft certanly ARE using it the way you describe (separating begin and end parts). A good example for it is the MVCForm class, provided by the mvc infrastracture. It implements `IDisposable` and writes the end tag for the form, while i cant see its implementation releasing ant resources (the writer used there to ouput the html seems to stay alive even after the form is disposed).

Alot has been written about the `using` block and how it "swallows" exceptions (a [wcf client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx) is a good sample, you can also find such discussions here, on SO). Personally i also feel alot of times that as much as it is convinient to use the `using` block, its not really 100% clear when it should and when it should not be used.

Of course, you actually CAN tell within the dispose method if you reached it with our without an error, by [adding an extra flag to your class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301548/1394380), and raising it within the `using` block, but this will work only if the person who will use your class will be aware of that flag

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in observing a problem with the design of try/finally blocks, which is in turn a problem with `using`: there is no clean way for code in a `finally` block to know whether code execution will continue with the statement following the `finally` block, or whether there is a pending exception which will be effectively take over as soon as the `finally` block executes.

I would really like to see a language feature in vb.net and C# which would allow a `finally` block to include an `Exception` parameter (e.g.

```
  try
  {
  }
  finally (Exception ex)
  {
    ...
  }
```

where the passed-in exception would be `null` if the `try` block exited normally, or would hold an exception if it did not.  Along with this, I would like to see an `IDisposableEx` interface, which would inherit `Dispose`, and include a `Dispose(Exception ex)` method with the expectation that user code would pass in the `ex` from the `finally` block.  Any exceptions which occurred during the `Dispose` could then wrap the passed-in exception (since both the passed-in exception, and the fact that an exception occurred in `Dispose`, would be relevant).

Failing that, it might be helpful to have .net provide a method which would indicate whether there was an exception pending in the current context.  Unfortunately, it's not clear what the exact semantics of such a method should be in various corner cases.  By contrast, the semantics of `finally (Exception ex)` would be perfectly clear.  Note, incidentally, that a proper implementation of `finally (Exception ex)` would require that the language make use of exception filters, but would not require exposing the ability to create arbitrary filters.

Comment: The code in the `finally` clause is *not supposed to care* whether an exception is thrown.  It should be able to, and should, do the exact same thing, regardless.  If you're only doing certain stuff when an exception happens, *that's what catch clauses are for*.

Comment: @cHao: A `catch` block is *supposed* to say "Okay, I know how to put everything back to normal". Although a `throw;` can be used to say "...Well, maybe I don't", using a catch with an unconditional rethrow is an abuse of `catch`; letting a `finally` know how a `catch` exited would be minor by comparison. Actually, the Framework allows one to define `fault` blocks, which would perhaps be most appropriate here; they only execute if an exception is thrown, but they leave the exception pending. Unfortunately, neither C# nor vb.net supports those. VB.net can at least emulate them, though; C# can't.

Comment: A `catch` block says no more than "if this type of exception is thrown, you need to do this".  It doesn't imply anything about "putting everything back to normal"; if that's all it were meant for, there wouldn't be a `throw;`.  There's a reason it's called `catch` and not `handle` or `fix`.  :)

Comment: @cHao: The exception mechanism in .net was explicitly and deliberately designed to allow the system to determine whether an exception is ultimately going to be handled before it allows `finally` blocks to run.  An active `catch` block tells the system "Okay, I've got this one--go ahead and run any nested `finally` blocks".  If your own code doesn't know whether an exception is going to ultimately be handled in such a fashion that `finally` blocks should be allowed to run, your code should let outer code make that determination.

Comment: ....wait, what?  `finally` blocks run *regardless*.  That's their whole reason for existing.  And any code outside the `try` or `catch` that depends on them not to have run yet, is fundamentally broken.  Although this is the first i've heard of code even being able to care about such things.  :P  You have a reference or something where this is talked about?  Cause it sounds *really* fishy...

Comment: @cHao: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2009/02/05/catch-rethrow-and-filters-why-you-should-care.aspx for starters.

Comment: OK, so basically, the difference is where the system reports the exception occurred.  I've seen this happen on rethrows; it's their main drawback, though its drawbackiness is a bit overstated.  (The stack frames before and after the rethrow seem to be correct -- difference is that the try point gets replaced with the rethrow point.)  Until and unless C# has exception filters, catching and rethrowing is the only useful way of doing much of anything like them. But either way, `finally (Exception e)` is simply a broken idea -- `finally` still should not care at all whether there was an exception.

Comment: @cHao: The `finally (Exception ex)` would be useful in a few contexts, especially if `using` could call `IDisposableEx.Dispose(Exceptionex)`.  Suppose, for example, an exception is thrown within an auto-rollback transaction scope, and code outside the scope expects to handle it, but the rollback itself fails.  I would suggest that the proper handling would be to throw an aggregate exception type, including both the original exception and the failed rollback, but doing that requires that the rollback code know what exception was pending, if any.

Comment: @cHao: Objects used for locking have some similar issues; many methods, if executed within a lock, will leave the guarded resource in a "safe" state if they complete normally, but might leave it in a corrupted state if they exit via an exception.  If a guarded resource is left in a corrupted state, other would-be users should not be allowed to proceed into the lock, but nor should they be left waiting forever.  Instead, they should receive an exception which would indicate that the guarded resource has been corrupted and consequently is not, and never will be, available.

Comment: I see no real reason they shouldn't be allowed to acquire the lock.  It's not a lock's job to guarantee against corruption; it's a lock's job to *lock*.  To guarantee exclusive access to itself.  No more, no less.  If the resource can't ensure its own integrity, it needs to be redesigned -- or at the very least, wrapped in something that can correct such things or signal their occurrence.

Comment: @cHao: A number of knowledgeable people including Eric Lippert have opined that releasing a lock on an entity which is in an unknown state is dangerous, and that it's better to leave would-be consumers blocked than to let them access a corrupt entity.  If that is true, I would think it would be better yet to have would-be consumer discover that the resource is dead, than simply wait forever for something that's never going to be available.

Comment: The thing *is* in a known state.  "Broken".  :P  The fact that it can not detect that and respond accordingly is a fundamental flaw in its design, and should be fixed *there*.  Not by bolting some junk onto exception handlers that says "if this exception happens, do this".  Especially when that's what `catch` *already says*.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are misusing the `IDisposable` interface.
A common practice is to use the interface to release unmanaged resources. Normally, the garbage collector will clean up objects, but in some cases - When yo do NOT longer need the object - you might need to manually clean up.

However in your case, you are not cleaning up an object that is not needed anymore; you are using it to force some logic. You should use another design for that.

Comment: `using` similar to what the OP does is a pretty common pattern.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I don't think that using the `using` keyword is the best option compared to a custom-designed solution for a specific purpose.

Comment: In some situations yes, in others no. For example `using` is pretty nice for transaction semantics. Razor also uses it for tag closing, but I'm not a fan of that.

Comment: @Aphelion: `using` is not only fine but also more than convenient for such cases. It's a really natural fit.

Comment: @Aphelion, while theoretically / semanticly you are correct, turns out microsoft are misusing the `using` block themselves..

Comment: The purpose of `IDisposable` is to allow a class to say: "I know something that needs to be done sometime between now and the end of the universe; I have the information and impetus to do it, and it's probable nobody else does.  Make sure you call my `IDisposable.Dispose` method once it's okay for me to do it, and before abandoning me.  Thanks."  Seems to me that the usage offered up here fits perfectly well within that pattern.

Comment: @supercat: Sorry, no.  The purpose of `IDisposable` is rather explicitly stated in the docs for the interface itself:  "[Defines a method to release allocated resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)".  Use beyond the scope of that is really misuse, even if it's MS themselves doing it.

Comment: @cHao: Can you provide for me an actual definition of "unmanaged resource"?

Comment: @supercat: I suppose "a resource that isn't managed" wouldn't suffice..?  :)  Basically, anything the CLR doesn't keep track of or automatically clean up for you.  Memory *generally* doesn't count (although a call to `GlobalAlloc`/`HeapAlloc`/etc could conceivably get you unmanaged memory, if you were feeling masochistic), but GDI/kernel/window handles do.

Comment: @cHao: That would leave open the question of "what is a resource"?  I would posit that a resource is any way in which any entity, anywhere in the universe, is altering its behavior on behalf of one object, to the detriment of others, and will continue to do so until further notice.  The relevance of a resource to `IDisposable` is that something will be left in a bad state unless some particular action is taken to get it out of that state, and the object implementing `IDisposable` knows what that state is.  For purposes of the original question, a file is in a "bad" state...

Comment: ...if it has unbalanced tags, and is in a good state if it has balanced tags.

Comment: @supercat: I thought i was pretty specific about what constitutes a "resource".  :)  Metaphysical states and balance of the cosmos or whatever, don't.  It is not the job of `IDisposable` to fix your karma, or your car, or your XML file.  It is to "release allocated resources".  Note, "release".  *Not* "tidy up".  It does not and *should not* care one bit whether your XML is well formed.  It cares whether the file handle you've indirectly acquired is still open, and closes it.  Because the file handle *is a resource* -- the well-formedness of your XML *isn't*.

Comment: @cHao: What "unmanaged resource" is held by the `IEnumerator<T>` created by iterator that calls `yield` within a `synclock`?  Locks are managed entirely within the CLR, and abandoning the only reference to a held lock will not prevent it from being garbage-collected, so what "unmanaged resource" would be held by the `IEnumerator<T>`?  Were the implementors of C# wrong to use `IDisposable<T>` to run their explicit or implied `finally` blocks?

Comment: @supercat: Yes, they were.  Because `IDisposable` is ***optional***.  If someone calls it, great.  If they don't, the world should not end.  But `finally` blocks have to run *regardless* -- again, it's their whole reason for being.  So now you have something that *has to run* depending on something that *might not ever be called*.  That's a recipe for all kinds of brokenness.  I appreciate that they tried to make iterators transparent to the language....but they added a bunch of stuff that quite frankly should not have been supported.

Comment: @supercat: And please don't bother mentioning `yield` within `lock` again.  That's broken code, period; i'm pretty sure even MS acknowledges that it shouldn't be done.  *For the very reasons i've already mentioned.*

Comment: @cHao: The amount of work that would be required for everyone who creates an `IEnumerable` to ensure that it gets `Dispose`d would be far less than the amount of work required to make many types of useful enumerable collections function correctly without memory leaks if their `Dispose` method isn't called (and complying with the latter condition would impose a performance hit as well).  Microsoft erred early on in suggesting that `Dispose` might be considered optional; code which fails to `Dispose` something without knowing the exact consequences of such failure is broken.

Comment: @supercat: No, `Dispose` being optional is not an error.  To make it necessary, without having a way for the CLR automatically call it, is an error.  The error is in *forgetting* that it's optional.  Or, in making everything derive from a type whose intrinsic properties include the ability to clean itself up, making any attempt to say "oh, well, this type can't *really* clean itself up; you have to call `Dispose` first" a violation of LSP.

Comment: @cHao: Objects do not get constructed without some code somewhere knowing what type they're going to be.  The LSP only applies to objects of *unknown* type.  For the constructor of a `ClassWhichRequiresDisposal` to impose conditions on its caller (including requiring that the caller see that its `IDisposable.Dispose` method gets called) is not a violation of the LSP, since the type of the object is known to be `ClassWhichRequiresDisposal`.  The fact that the *non*-generic `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` may return a class which implements `IDisposable` is a violation of the LSP, but...

Comment: @supercat: If i have a function that takes a `Thingie`, and the object passed to me just *happens* to be of some subtype that implements `IDisposable`, i don't have to care.  Because my function has every right to assume that the properties of `Thingie` (and by extension, those of `Object`) hold.  I can use it, squirrel it away, whatever i feel like.  And most importantly, *i have no obligation whatsoever to Dispose it.*  Because `Thingie` doesn't need disposal.

Comment: @supercat: And no, LSP applies *always*.  There are no loopholes.  There is no "unknown type" requirement.  LSP says, "Let q(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then q(y) should be provable for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T."  There are no other conditions or restrictions.

Comment: ...the fault lies with the definition of that interface (whose use is largely deprecated, for that reason among others).  The code required for an implementation to prevent memory leaks if someone calls `GetEnumerator()` a million times on a long-lived object without ever calling `Dispose` may be substantial (among other things, the collection would have to create a `WeakReference` for each outstanding enumerator, and poll such objects to see if their target has been collected).  Better to stipulate that proper use of `GetEnumerator()` requires calling `Dispose` on the returned `IEnumerator`.